# $\alpha \wedge \beta = 0$ iff $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra

I have been given the following problem:

> Let $\alpha$ be a nowhere-zero 1-form. Prove that for a (p+1)-form $\beta$ $(p\geq0)$, one has $\alpha \wedge \beta = 0$ if and only if $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma$ for some p-form $\gamma$. [Hint: You might like to do it on $\mathbb{R}^n$ fist. Partition of unity is useful in the general case].

It is true that $\alpha \wedge \alpha = 0$ for 1-forms (and $k$-forms whenever $k$ is odd I believe), so the if statement is easy.
However, for the converse, I couldn't find an argument even on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried to do this locally first by writing $\alpha = \sum_i \alpha_i(x) dx_i$, $\beta = \sum_J \beta_J(x) dx_J$ where $J = j_1j_2...j_{p+1}$ and $1 \leq j_1 \leq j_2 \leq...\leq j_{p+1} \leq dim(M)$ for whatever the dimension of M might be. Then

$\alpha \wedge \beta = \sum_{i,J} \alpha_i(x) \beta_J(x) dx_i\wedge dx_J$.

It is given that $\alpha$ is nonvanishing, but nothing is known about $\beta$. The sum seems to be a combinatorial thing if you want to arrange it into a form with $dx_i\wedge dx_J$ all distinct. Anyhow, I cannot see how to rewrite this expression in such a form that it becomes clear that one can sort of factor out $\alpha$.

Comment: Locally, you can choose a basis of $T_xM^\ast$ containing $\alpha$. Write $\beta$ in that basis.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it.

Comment: Write $\beta = \sum \beta_J \alpha_{j_1} \wedge \alpha_{j_2} \wedge ... \wedge \alpha_{j_{p+1}}$ with $\alpha_{j_1} = \alpha$. Then all $\beta_J$ for which the set $J$ does not contain 1 must vanish, so $\beta$ can be written as a linear combination of terms $\beta_J \alpha_{j_1} \wedge \alpha_{j_2} \wedge ... \wedge \alpha_{j_{p+1}}$ with $j_k = 1$ for some $1\leq k \leq p+1$. But then one can factor out a term $\alpha$ from each of the terms in the expansion of $\beta$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: For the global case, can you write $\alpha = \sum_i \rho_i \alpha|_{U_i}$, so that on each $U_i$ you have $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma_i$. Then $\beta = \sum_i \rho_i \alpha \wedge \gamma_i = \alpha \wedge \gamma$ for $\gamma = \sum_i \rho_i \gamma_i$? Here $\{\rho_i\}$ is a partition of unity subordinate to the cover \{U_i\}$.

Comment: I would be surprised if that didn't work out, but I haven't checked it myself.

Comment: @Peter, I don't think you can just write $\beta = \sum \beta_J \alpha_{j_1} \wedge \alpha_{j_2} \wedge \dotsc \wedge \alpha_{j_{p+1}}$ with $\alpha_{j_1} = \alpha$, because it seems that in this way you're already assuming what you're trying to prove, i.e. that $\beta = \alpha \wedge \gamma$, no? I mean, $\alpha$ itself is a $1$-form, so a linear combination of $\mathrm{d}x_i$, so why would you be able to write $\beta$ like that?